# Why do we require the set of events to be a sigma algebra?

Tags: probability

In probability theory, we want the set of events to form a sigma algebra. Why is it necessary? For example in case of rolling a dice, we might ask what is the probability of an event $A$ (we get a number divisible by 4), and of event $B$ (getting a number divisible by 3). We might obviously be interested in complementary events (not divisible by 4 or not divisible by 3). However, the rules of sigma algebra say the union of those events should also be an event, and we might not be interested in such an event. I thought we define what events we wish to consider, it shouldn't be dictated by sigma algebra.

Please give a straightforward explanation why this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

In general we will be interested in what happens if both events $A$ and $B$ occur, i.e. the intersection, or in what happens if one of the events happens, i.e. the union.

Edit: to add an example, consider the event $A$ it rains tomorrow and $B$ the sun shines tomorrow. Think about what intersection and union means here and you might see a rainbow, pun intended.

Comment: To put in other words: to consider the probability you need to consider "all possible events", and not just "events we wish to consider".

Comment: For a finite sample space (such as the ones for rolling dice), all possible events (subsets of the sample space) are typically included in the sigma-algebra. If there are $k$ outcomes in the sample space, then there are $2^k$ subsets of the sample space (including the null event and the whole space itself). For sample spaces such as $R^n$, it is not possible to assign probabilities to all subsets in a consistent way. Then the sigma-algebra is built up from intervals, so that any event of practical interest can have a probability.